# how to open a different browser in telerik test script

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, telerik

I am testing a chat functionality on the user interface.
so I will be logging in as user 1 from IE and log in in as user 2 on Firefox.

So I want to know what is the syntax to do this in telerik test file using c#.

I have checked online and have found various links for cross browser testing which is mainly running the same test on different browser. 
But I want to launch a new browser from a test script

Can someone please share some inputs and any helpful links?

thanks

Comment: are you familiar with javascript.. don't they have a window.open() function...?

Comment: selenium webdrver has something like the firefox driver which will open a firefox window. in similar way I want to open a firefox browser from the code and not by recording it manually. Is there a way to do this in C#?

Answer (score 0):

you could try something as simple as this

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("firefox.exe", "http://www.msn.com");
```

if firefox is not added to your %Path% then fully qualify the location of where the .exe is like this

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox>firefox.exe", "http://www.msn.com");
```

Comment: perhaps you need to show what it is you're doing because this is pretty straight forward.. show what code you are using .. also show what your using section looks like in the header